# How to run yum inside a docker container on a partially isolated host?

Tags: docker, yum, http-proxy, docker-network

I have a machine that is on a semi-isolated network. I have to use proxy to connect to the internet. I have verified that on my host, after I set http_proxy environment variable, I can receive update from public yum repository.

Now I am trying to do the same thing inside a docker container on my machine, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$docker run --rm -it --net=host rhel /bin/bash
[root@MyCont] http_proxy=http://myproxy:1234/
[root@MyCont] echo -e "[base] \nname=CentOS-7 - Base - centos.com\nbaseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/\$basearch/\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7" > /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS7-Base-centos.repo \
&& yum clean all \
&& yum install -y openssh-server  openssh-clients
```

I brought up my container in host network mode, so I assume I should have the same network stack as my host in my container. Therefore, if I set the http_proxy properly, I should have the same yum behavior inside and outside container.

Is it possible to run yum inside a docker container whose host is on a semi-isolated network that needs http_proxy to access yum?

Answer (score 1):

you should install software inside your image on a build

thus use yum install in your dockerfile

however, if for some reason you need to yum inside the container then ....

```
docker run -e http_proxy=http://10.9.2.2:8080
```

note if yum install isn't working then try ...

```
yum update
```

first - for some reason this helps!

also use ...

```
docker exec -it containerName bash
```

to enter into the container, then try execute your yum command. export any proxy env vars as required.

Comment: (1) I have specified everything in my Dockerfile already, but for some reason it's been failing to build at yum, so I am trying to run yum command inside the container to debug. (2) using run -e is essentially the same as using `export http_proxy=...` inside the container as I had attempted. (3) I need to configure the proxy properly first before I can use yum update (4) Hence the question would be what additional proxy env vars would be required, if any, for me to run, say `yum update` etc.

Comment: export https_proxy

Comment: I have tried http_proxy, https_proxy and ftp_proxy, none of them works though

Answer (score 1):

Like danday74 said, you have to use '**export** https_proxy=http...'.
Works in my environment. Just to be safe, I export both http_proxy and https_proxy.